# Как обособлять "главное"

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда слово "главное" является вводным словом, а когда - подлежащим(и надо ставить тире)?

Comment: Приведите пример хоть одной фразы, в отношении которой у вас возникают подобные затруднения с грамматическим разбором.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Член предложения - когда к нему можно задать вопрос. Подлежащее - когда потом расшифровывается, что именно главное. Вводное слово - если его можно изъять из предложения и смысл при этом не нарушится.

Подлежащее:

`А главное - успеть вовремя на работу.`

Изъять не получается.

Вводное:

`А тебе, главное, нужно успеть вовремя на работу.`

Тут можно изъять и предложение останется нормальным.

Но можно это же переделать, чтобы было как подлежащее:

`А для тебя главное, что нужно успеть вовремя на работу.`

Тут изъять нельзя. Тире не всегда обязательно (тут `что` его заменяет).

Изъятие - это лучшая проверка для вводных слов/словосочетаний.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы что-то напутали. _Член предложения... Подлежащее... В этом случае его можно изъять и смысл не нарушиться._ Разве? И — "нарушится".

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил + улучшил последний пример.